# Anyone know plumjs and plum.shop? Cannot even get basic demo working

Tags: javascript, jquery, e-commerce, shopping-cart

I am trying to implement the demo version of the plum.shop code. Plum.shop is a nice shopping cart library you can get at Code Canyon (http://codecanyon.net/item/plumshop-a-jquery-shopping-cart/427746)

However, I've set up a JSFiddle with the requisite external libraries and I'm not even getting a decent error message and nothing appears to be happening. It should be as simple as this HTML:

```
<h2>Shopping Cart</h2>
<div id="cart">
<p>Your shopping cart is empty.</p>
</div>

<div class="shop-product" id="sku-01">
    <span class="title">My awesome product</span>
    <span class="price">$10.00</span>
    <input class="purchase" 
        type="button" 
    value="Add to cart"/>
</div>
```

and this Jquery flavored JS:

```
$('#cart').plum('shop',{
    cartitem: '{title} — {pricesingle} ' + '× {quantity} — ' + '{pricetotal}',
    paypaluser: 'hello',
    paypaldomain: 'robocreatif.com'
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ruzel/6bswm/4/

Even when I have gotten the right alchemy of plumjs and jquery to work (on my server) I still get no reporting of any plum.shop variables (e.g. `{title}` or `{pricesingle}`

Comment: Now that plum.shop is no longer for sale, can you please give me a copy of plum.shop so I can use it?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this line at the end before the  tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="example-plum-shop-configuration.js"></script>
```

Also, make sure the file is located there.